# Exact text match in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following code:

```
<div id="MetricsParentModelList">
   <ul>
      <li class="cModel" style=""><a href="#">Hello</a></li>
      <li class="cModel" style=""><a href="#">Hello World</a></li>
      <li class="cModel" style=""><a href="#">Hello World 123</a></li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

I want to add active class to `li` by comparing the text of the anchor tag. I can't use jQuery's contains because if i want to add active class to "Hello", then active class will be added to all li elements. I have used jQuery's filter but somehow its not working. Code is:

```
$("#MetricsParentModelList li a").filter(function() {
    return $(this).text() === TextToCompare;
}).parent().addClass('active');
```

Comment: https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/wYKaqo.. working fine ..except  missing dot infornt of parent()

Comment: Could there be whitespace around the text? Try using `$(this).text().trim()`

Comment: no there is no whitespace . .@Barmar

Comment: Not working for me . .:( @NagaSaiA

Comment: did you try hard coding TextToCompare to "Hello" and do you see any console errors

Comment: It is working for me too. Can you explain why it isn't working for you? We might have gotten your problem wrong.

Comment: Thanks @Barmar. Got it done by using trim() function

Answer (score 1):

You can use jquery's [.each](https://api.jquery.com/each/) function. And your code will be more readable.

```js
var TextToCompare = "Hello World 123";

$("#MetricsParentModelList li a").each(function() {
    if($(this).text() === TextToCompare) {
        $(this).parent().addClass('active');
    }
});
```

```css
.active { background-color: #ccc; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="MetricsParentModelList">
   <ul>
      <li class="cModel" style=""><a href="#">Hello</a></li>
      <li class="cModel" style=""><a href="#">Hello World</a></li>
      <li class="cModel" style=""><a href="#">Hello World 123</a></li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Why should he *try this* ?  Every time you answer a question try to give explanations of what you're doing and why should the OP(and in fact anyone who sees your answer) follow your answer.

Comment: @ths sorry for that, I'll update my answer and I will follow your recommendation in other answers.

Comment: thanks for your comprehension, by doing so we keep SO clean and helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you need to wrap your JS in a `$(document).ready(function(){})` or `$(()=>{})` as a shorthand.

```js
$(() => {
  $("#MetricsParentModelList li a").filter(function() {
      return $(this).text().toLowerCase() === "hello";
  }).parent().addClass('active');
});
```

```css
.active{
 background-color: #f00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="MetricsParentModelList">
   <ul>
      <li class="cModel" style=""><a href="#">Hello</a></li>
      <li class="cModel" style=""><a href="#">Hello World</a></li>
      <li class="cModel" style=""><a href="#">Hello World 123</a></li>
   </ul>
</div>
```